# Correct word for something less believed in society

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What is an appropriate word to describe something, a section of society wants or looks forward to it or believes in, but rest of the society/majority will not accept it at all or gives importance to it.
Like online petitions (in my country atleast)

Comment: Sorry, you want to describe the forward-looking part of the society or the more conservative part?

Comment: I want to describe it as somethink some of us hope to achieve but clearly at present we cannot as whole.

Comment: Something like an aspiration? :a goal or objective that is strongly desired.

Comment: Yeah but not possible to achieve because of mass disapproval

Comment: I think somewhere "conspiracy" sneaks in, on the part of one side or the other.  And sociologists probably have a term for some public good that is unattainable due to public opposition.

Comment: How about *dream*?

Answer (score 2):

Either **fringe** or **minority**, depending on how small the participating fraction is, plus **belief**, **tradition**, **practice**, **custom** or **cause**.

You could add **diminishing** or **growing** to indicate whether this segment of society is changing in size.

For example,

*Petitions have always been a **fringe cause** in ....*

*Blue elephants remain a **minority belief** in many parts of the world*

Words like **folklore**, **lore**, **legend**, or **myth** imply that the tradition is old and that relatively few people believe or follow it. However, both may be deeply integrated into the society, although in a less literal fashion than originally presented. These can be used to indicate why the custom persists. For example,

*Among a diminishing minority, the **myth** that jumping on one foot to cure the common cold persists.*

Answer (score 0):

Probably [utopia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Utopia)  carries the connotation you are describing:

> - An impractical, idealistic scheme for social and political reform.

Comment: This suggestion implies improvement and, in common use, perfection. Used by itself it's meant to refer to More's Utopia (1516), which is a place. Even when used as an adjective (e.g. a *utopian ideal*, a *utopian approach to voting*), it still doesn't imply that only a minority of people believe it. In fact, it may be that most believe it in theory but see it as impossible (or impractical) to implement in practise.

Comment: In practical usage 'utopia' is used to refer to political reforms which, for some reason, are considered  very difficult or impossible to carry out, and I understand this is what OP is referring to.